# File google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-2.3

I have got this error :

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: File google-services.json is missing. The 
Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

I hope someone help me, I tried everything nearly ,but I failed!!

---

Note: Make sure that I have downloaded "google-services.json",then putted it in MyProjectName/app

---

This is my project's build gradle(project):

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded google-services.json from your project which is registered using your current package name

Comment: I am sure, I entered my package name there

Comment: Did you sole your problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the *Firebase Console* you have to navigate to your *Project Settings* and select **google-services.json** in your connected *Android app*.

You have to place this file into your `app` directory in your project directory.

Comment: I already did!!... I placed  **google-services.json** into my 'app' directory

Comment: Have my app's key be the same key in the **google-services.json** file(current key)???

Comment: @osamaastal I'm having the same issue! The file is there in my app directory. it works if I downgrade flutter but then I get issues with other things which is why I wanted to upgrade in the first place!

Comment: i already did it in app level directory but still it gives me the same error